# After Sidekiq start, jobs in queue start but never finish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a problem with sidekiq,

On my local env, when I already have some jobs in queue and I start sidekiq, `bundle exec sidekiq`, these jobs start but never finish (see example below). These jobs should be done in max 1 or 2 seconds). It seems to happen with every jobs, not specifically with the example's one.

It forces me to close sidekiq and flush redis `$redis.flushall`. Then I restart rails THEN I restart sidekiq and THEN I enque new jobs, it works...

Do you have any idea of what's happening?

Thanks in advance!

**My environment**

- ruby 2.6.0
- sidekiq 6.0.6
- Rails 6.0.2.1

**Example**

My job:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(variant_id)
    puts 'UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob start'

    # do the job

    puts 'UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob end'
  end
end
```

bundle exec sidekiq

```
               m,
               `$b
          .ss,  $$:         .,d$
          `$$P,d$P'    .,md$P"'
           ,$$$$$b/md$$$P^'
         .d$$$$$$/$$$P'
         $$^' `"/$$$'       ____  _     _      _    _
         $:     ,$$:       / ___|(_) __| | ___| | _(_) __ _
         `b     :$$        \___ \| |/ _` |/ _ \ |/ / |/ _` |
                $$:         ___) | | (_| |  __/   <| | (_| |
                $$         |____/|_|\__,_|\___|_|\_\_|\__, |
              .d$$                                       |_|


2020-03-26T09:27:10.758Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Booted Rails 6.0.2.1 application in development environment
2020-03-26T09:27:10.759Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Running in ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-darwin17]
2020-03-26T09:27:10.759Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2020-03-26T09:27:10.760Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2020-03-26T09:27:10.761Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.0.6 with redis options {:id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-79574", :url=>nil}
2020-03-26T09:27:10.776Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2020-03-26T09:27:10.805Z pid=79574 tid=oui1srrua class=UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob jid=7d9ff854d1cbd8f127385faf INFO: start
2020-03-26T09:27:10.808Z pid=79574 tid=oui1srs5a class=UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob jid=7b0aca12380f5214baa90c46 INFO: start






^C2020-03-26T09:28:51.868Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Shutting down
2020-03-26T09:28:51.868Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Terminating quiet workers
2020-03-26T09:28:51.872Z pid=79574 tid=oui1srrf6 INFO: Scheduler exiting...
2020-03-26T09:28:51.980Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Pausing to allow workers to finish...
2020-03-26T09:29:16.842Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii WARN: Terminating 2 busy worker threads
2020-03-26T09:29:16.842Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii WARN: Work still in progress [#<struct Sidekiq::BasicFetch::UnitOfWork queue="queue:default", job="{\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"class\":\"UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob\",\"args\":[2209],\"jid\":\"7d9ff854d1cbd8f127385faf\",\"created_at\":1585048833.1967769,\"enqueued_at\":1585048833.196963}">, #<struct Sidekiq::BasicFetch::UnitOfWork queue="queue:default", job="{\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"class\":\"UpdateVariantInDraftOrdersJob\",\"args\":[2209],\"jid\":\"7b0aca12380f5214baa90c46\",\"created_at\":1585048838.899363,\"enqueued_at\":1585048838.899456}">]
2020-03-26T09:29:16.846Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Pushed 2 jobs back to Redis
2020-03-26T09:29:16.898Z pid=79574 tid=oui10vpii INFO: Bye!
```

Comment: I have a similiar problem I think - did you find a solution?

Comment: I also have this issue, did you find a solution or workaround?